# Is it possible to disable redshift on just one screen from a multi monitor setup?

Tags: redshift, contrast

I've got an e-ink display and would like to disable redshift on just this screen, but keep it enabled on the other two monitors. How do I setup this? Is it possible to increase contrast as well? (The Chrome high contrast extension is good for the browser.)

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I figured out a solution for me. Run:

`redshift  -m randr:crtc=2 -O 9000` for the redshift-disabled third monitor (sometimes I use 8000).

And run

```
redshift  -m randr:crtc=0 -O 3000
redshift  -m randr:crtc=1 -O 3000
```

It's my color temperature for both the other monitors.

Comment: Big thanks for showing how to select monitor adjusted by randr. The official page says about `screen` attribute which doesn't work. But putting the below section in the `redshift.conf` file does the job of selecting the first monitor:

 `[randr]
 crtc=0`